# getting error while creating table as ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in oracle database sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a table but get an error as ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in oracle database

```
create table player_info
(player_id varchar2(200) primary key,
User_id varchar2(100) not null,
Level varchar2(200) not null,
HP number(1000) not null,
Map_id varchar2(200) not null,
Model_id varchar(200) not null,
Money varchar2(10000) not null,
Boss_killed varchar2(100));
```

Comment: It's already pointed out that LEVEL is a reserved word.  Put a little thought into developing some _naming standards_ and you will forever avoid this problem.  My personal naming standard for column names is to use the format "adjective_noun".  (FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, etc).  This not only avoids trying to use a reserved word, it also makes the code more self-documenting, which will be appreciated by others that use the same tables.  I also standardize abbreviations, like 'NBR' for 'number'.  Occasionally it makes sense to break the 'adjective_noun' format, but it needs to be well recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong in your statement. Each of the ones below will cause an error.

- LEVEL is a "reserved word", you cannot use this as a column name. Here is the full list: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612
- NUMBER(1000) is not valid - what are you trying to achieve here ? The precision of the number should be between 1 and 38 (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) - what would the "1000" indicate ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because LEVEL is a reserved word in Oracle, use another word instead.