# while creating table getting error ORA-01727: numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38) in SQLOracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting error while creating a table :

> numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38)

```
create table player_info
(player_id varchar2(100) primary key,
User_id varchar2(100) not null,
Level_no number(37) not null,
HP number(100) not null,
Map_id varchar2(200) not null,
Model_id varchar(200) not null,
Money number(37) not null,
Boss_killed number(37));
```

Comment: How is this significantly different from what you posted an hour earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564620/getting-error-while-creating-table-as-ora-00904-invalid-identifier-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a typo, but you have defined your `HP` column to be a `NUMBER` with a width of 100 precision.  Change to a lower valid value and the code works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE player_info (
    player_id varchar2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    User_id varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
    Level_no number(37) NOT NULL,
    HP number(37) NOT NULL,
    Map_id varchar2(200) NOT NULL,
    Model_id varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Money number(37) NOT NULL,
    Boss_killed number(37)
);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Number can only be between 1 and 38. You can add another paramter for the scale.
Look here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use `NUMBER` datatype with no scale/precision; looks that's what you really want.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE player_info
  2  (
  3     player_id     VARCHAR2 (100) PRIMARY KEY,
  4     User_id       VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  5     Level_no      NUMBER  NOT NULL,
  6     HP            NUMBER  NOT NULL,
  7     Map_id        VARCHAR2 (200) NOT NULL,
  8     Model_id      VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
  9     Money         NUMBER  NOT NULL,
 10     Boss_killed   NUMBER
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```